# Samba authentication does not work

Tags: samba

I am trying to share folder via network. I was able to connect to that folder remotely as long as it was not restricted to valid users.
Content of my smb.conf file :

```
[sdilena]
path = /sdilena
available = yes
read only = no
browsable = yes
writable = yes
public = yes
valid users = samba
```

I am trying to connect to it using folowing command :

```
mount -t cifs -o username=samba //192.168.0.103/sdilena /folder
```

After I enter the password, it always return an error "Permision Denied"

Where could be the problem ?

Comment: Did you `sudo smbpasswd -a <uname>` for your valid users?

Comment: I totally forgot that. Now it works, thank you. Write it as answer, so I can mark it as solution, and you will get some points :-)

Comment: Now I see, you probably do not need that :-).

Comment: @JohnRonald: Note that you can also up-vote a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I Created samba user with password.
Set my serer to static P address 192.168.0.210

Then I added this to make clients find host in samba config file.
interfaces = 127.0.0.0/8 192.168.0.210
bind interfaces only = true

Here is my share setup it even works on my Android Tablet.

```
[WWW]
comment = HTML Directory
path = /var/www/html/
available = yes
valid users = my_samba_username
read only = no
browseable = yes
public = yes
```

List SMB shares

```
smbclient –L IP_Address –U username
```

What I used:
smbmount //192.168.0.210/share_file /mnt –o username=santosh,workgroup=workgroupnam

This supposed to work.

```
mount –t smbfs IP_Address:/sharename /mountpoint –o username=userid,workgroup=workgroupname
```

Could it be you need to change (`chmod` `chgrp` `chown`) to your `/var/www/html` or whatever is your shared directory, I did that also.

I am just telling you what I just did maybe it will help.